# where $variable = $variable

Tags: php, mysql, variables

having a bit of a problem where i have a dropdown in my html and a text entry i am then trying to use those in a mysql query 
both criteria and querytype do return values when i echo them it is just the select query that is returning no values where it should

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("***********************");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$querytype = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['querytype']);
$criteria = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['criteria']);

$query= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT trackingnumber FROM 'OrderDB' WHERE '$querytype' = '$criteria'");
$result = mysqli_fetch_array ($query);
header('Location: http://trackyourpackage.uk/track.php?oid=' . $result);
?>
```

Comment: Remove the quotes in `FROM 'OrderDB' WHERE '$querytype'`.

Comment: Google. "Parameterized Queries". And "SQL Injection". Now. No, really. Now.

Comment: For a table or field name, you can use _backticks_, especially if it _might_ be a reserved word, but you can't use straight quotes ' or ".

Comment: Use [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or **PDO** with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements)

Comment: nope returns nothing again

Comment: this code it's **Dangeously** vulnerable to a SQL injection attack.

Comment: Well then, make sure your form elements are indeed named, and/or check if you have any results by doing `var_dump($query);` btw, you're using more than one parameter for `$con = mysqli_connect("***********************");` right? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: I'm' so glad I don't put in "answers" anymore. Seems that lately, many of the questions asked seem to open great big cans of worms.

Comment: Show us your entire HTML form as well as what's inside `track.php`

Comment: <form id="contact" method="post" action="search.php">

what to search:<select name="querytype">
<option value="select">Please select...</option>
<option value="postcode">postcode</option>
<option value="surname">surname</option>
<option value="email">email</option>
<option value="rc number">rc number</option>
<br />
<input type="text" name="criteria">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</div>
</tr>
</thead>
</body> </html> </table>

Comment: <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("*******"); 
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}


 $result= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TABLE 1");
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($row['COL8'])){
      echo $row['COL8'];
 }

?>

Comment: Far as I can see then, your issue may lie inside `track.php`, because seeing that you're not actually fetching results using `$result = mysqli_fetch_array ($query);` will do "I don't know what".

Comment: You're using `SELECT * FROM TABLE 1`? Really? If that is your actual code, two things; 1) `table` is a reserved word. 2) If your table is `1` then you can't use single numbers unless wrapped backticks, same thing goes for `table`. So, wrap `TABLE 1` in backticks.

Comment: but ive tried to echo $query in search.php and it returns nothing

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> $result = mysqli_fetch_array ($query);
> header('Location: http://trackyourpackage.uk/track.php?oid=' . $result);
> ```

`mysql_fetch_array()` returns an array. Converting an array to a string results in the literal string `"Array"`. You need to use an array index:

```
header('Location: http://trackyourpackage.uk/track.php?oid=' . $result[0]);
```